# Why does this XUL code works and the Javascript equivalent doesn't?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

xul way:

```
<toolbar id="PersonalToolbar">
  <toolbarbutton 
    id="Testing-Doit-Button2"
    class="bookmark-item pagerank"
    tooltiptext="Do it!"
    oncommand="testing_doit();" 
  />
</toolbar>
```

javascript way:

```
function createBookmarkItem() {
    const XUL_NS = "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul";
    var item = document.createElementNS(XUL_NS, "toolbarbutton");
    item.setAttribute("id", "Testing-Doit-Button2");
    item.setAttribute("class", "bookmark-item pagerank");
    item.setAttribute("tooltiptext", "Do it!");
    item.setAttribute("oncommand", "testing_doit();");
    return item;
}
function placeBookmarkItem() {
 var toolbar = document.getElementById("PersonalToolbar");
 var button = createBookmarkItem();
 toolbar.appendChild(button);
}
placeBookmarkItem();
```

The xul way shows a button. The Javascript way shows a button when I go to the Javascript Shell of the Extension Developer's Extension, then click enumerateWindows(), then click chrome://browser/content/browser.xul, then type the code, then hit enter. The Javascript way doesn't show a button when I include button.js in button.xul. Why?

Comment: You might rephrase the title of the question.  It appears you are asking what the difference between Javascript and XUL is.

Comment: it's 1ooking 1ike a 1oad problem, 1o1

Comment: A part of the code that I didn't quote here and that had an error made not work the part of the code that I quoted here and that didn't have an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A part of the code that I didn't quote here and that had an error made not work the part of the code that I quoted here and that didn't have an error. Take a look at "[I add 10 functions to a code, I don’t even call any of them, but the code stops working!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763726/i-add-10-functions-to-a-code-i-dont-even-call-any-of-them-but-the-code-stops-w)" for more information.

Comment: In an other person's computer, it does. In mine, it doesn't. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770728/getelementbyidbookmarksbarcontent-appendchildbutton-is-interpreted-as-getel for more information.

Comment: Now, it does in my computer! Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783176/i-try-to-add-a-new-button-to-firefox-but-its-the-old-button-that-gets-added for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the placeBookmarkItem(); inside the documents onload event. The javascript gets executed before the document is in place.
Otherwise place the `<script/>` element just before the `</window>` element in the end of the document.

Comment: There is an overlay instead of a window element.