# I try to add a new button to Firefox, but it's the old button that gets added!

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon, xul

Once, I tried adding a button with "bookmark-item pagerank" as class to PersonalToolbar. Now, the code...

```
function createToolbarButton() {
    const XUL_NS = "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul";
    var anitem = document.createElementNS(XUL_NS, "toolbarbutton");
    anitem.setAttribute("id", "Testing-Doit-Button2");
    anitem.setAttribute("class", "toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional pagerank");
    anitem.setAttribute("label", "PageRank");
    anitem.setAttribute("tooltiptext", "Do it!");
    anitem.setAttribute("oncommand", "testing_doit();");
    return anitem;
}
function placeToolbarButton() {
    var bar = document.getElementById("nav-bar");
    var newitem = createToolbarButton();
    bar.appendChild(newitem);
}
placeToolbarButton();
```

...adds a button with "bookmark-item pagerank" instead of "toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional pagerank" as class to PersonalToolbar instead of nav-bar!

How to solve this problem?

UPDATED! I hadn't noticed that the function names were still the old ones! I want to create and place a toolbar button, not a bookmark item! I'm sorry!

Comment: Add the following line of code and see if it still has the old behavior:  `DIE HORRIBLY;`  If so, the new code isn't running at all; you forgot a step somewhere.

Comment: If you isolate the code it works fine. Perhaps it's something in your other part of the code? Could you post the complete sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, it works! In the Javascript Shell, typing a function with the same name as an other function in button.js and hiting enter, even if they have different behaviors, will call the function in button.js

By the way, to use the Javascript Shell the way I used, you have to install Extension Developer's Extension, then go Firefox -> Tools -> ExtensionDeveloper -> Javascript Shell -> enumerateWindows() -> chrome://browser/content/browser.xul

Comment: Glad you could solve it yourself. You should mark your own answer as solution!

Comment: I am so relieved. I even used bounty. I have a complicated nsIChannel problem to solve now. I don't know how to use that thing! cya